# Are questions that talk about "today", "recently", etc. considered harmful?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Across many SE, but especially 'current events' sorts of SE like Politics, I find myself seeing questions that start with "Today..." or "Recently..." or "This morning..." or whatnot, and it always makes me grit my teeth a bit.

There are lots of useful questions from years and years ago; these are not ephemeral documents.  Absolute dates are much more appropriate, in my opinion.

Am I just being unreasonable about this?

Yes, I know I can edit them myself, and I often do.

Still, it makes me wonder if there's some opportunity across all the */tour to help people write better questions.

Is there, in fact, one or more well-regarded generic-ish "How To Write Good Questions" document around?  I don't recall seeing one, but I also didn't look very hard, but *also* it's the sort of thing that would most benefit exactly those people who are not likely to look very hard.

Comment: We used to have a "Too Localized" close reason for such occasions, but SE decided to do away with it.  Joel Spolsky used to describe these kinds of questions like this: "Why is that green car parked outside my house?"

Comment: There is [REPREX AKA MCVE AKA MWE and SSCCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (but not on this meta site). The *TeX - LaTeX* Stack Exchange site has [an awesome one](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231). [Jon Skeet also wrote one](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Harmful? No. Every post on Stack Exchange is dated, so if someone says “today,” we know which day, month, and year they are talking about. It is arguably more clear if the date is edited into the body of the post, but not absolutely necessary, in my opinion.

Often, a post author will use a word like “today” or “recently” to provide some context for a story, and the actual date doesn’t matter. In these cases, editing the actual date into the post just adds unnecessary information.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you that Q&As on many Main sites should be as timeless as possible, and that when the date of a piece of information is important it should be written explicitly.

I would probably edit out "Today..." or "Recently..." or "This morning..." **if it amounted to no more than chit chat in that particular post** but I would only do that while making other improvements.

One Q&A you could review as a possible model for writing a Meta post for your site is [Asking good Questions for GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 2):

By using the "posts" URL (see [Why is there no link to timeline of the post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262678/why-is-there-no-link-to-timeline-of-the-post)) you can get to a detailed table listing dates of creation, editing,... quickly.

And even the ordinary views make it easy to determine when content was written or modified.

That relieves the authors of including such details manually. Of course you take away that information when copying content without linking to the source, but that you should not do anyway.

Of course, in special cases it might be helpful or not to agree to a common terminology to address "common" topics. See [Is there a good term/phrase to denote the "current events"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337953/is-there-a-good-term-phrase-to-denote-the-current-events) just as an example).